# traer una imagen desde sql server a android

Tags: java, android, sql, json, nodejs

buenas tardes gente, la consulta, básicamente es, 
tengo una imagen en una base de datos de sql server (varbinary), y lo traigo a través de un json con un servicio restful hecho con node, junto a otros datos; al traerlo del json, lo trato como un string debido a que es el único formato que conozco para llevarlo a una entidad intermedia.
la cuestión esta en que intente hacerla conversión a base64, y de ahi transformarlo en un byte[] pero me tira error de conversion, habra alguna otra forma para hacerlo?

el metodo que uso es el siguiente:

```
byte[] decodeString = new byte[0];
            try {
                decodeString = Base64.decode(i.getImagen(), Base64.NO_OPTIONS);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap decodebitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodeString,
                   0, decodeString.length);
            imagen.setImageBitmap(decodebitmap);
```

Comment: ¿Que error te pinta?

Comment: y guardastes la imagen en base de datos b64?

Comment: @Hictus este es el mensaje que me tira Bad Base64 input character decimal XXX in array position 0 (los numeros no los recuerdo precisamente)

Comment: @JackNavaRow esta es la query con la que comence a guardar la imagen ` UPDATE Products SET ProductImage=(select BulkColumn FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'Imagepath', Single_Blob)) WHERE ProductId='SomeProductCode' `